# how to go back to previous fragment from a activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

so here's the situaion i have activity A with fragment userprofile and when user click on edit the fragment is replaced with editprofile so when the user click on the imagebutton the below code is executed to select the image from the gallery.
the problem when the activity is closed it goes back fragment userprofile.
Activty A is resumed not with fragment editprofile but with userprofile.

Code for mainactivity which inflates the fragment container

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
//String institudeID;

String institudeID;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton profile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
            UserProfile newFragment = new UserProfile();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    ImageButton discussion = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.discussionthread);
    discussion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
            Discussion_Main newFragment = new Discussion_Main();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    ImageButton news = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.news);
    news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
            News_Main newFragment = new News_Main();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    bhhooo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
            BHHOOO_Main newFragment = new BHHOOO_Main();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    ImageButton chat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.chat);
    chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
            Chat_Main newFragment = new Chat_Main();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    institudeID = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    //Log.i("LOG", institudeID);


    if(getIntent().hasExtra("register") == true){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id",institudeID);
        bundle.putBoolean("register", true);
        Edit_Profile newFragment = new Edit_Profile();
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    else {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", institudeID);
        News_Main newFragment = new News_Main();
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragement_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

From here when user press on the profile button the fragment container is inflated with  userprofile and then user can click on editprfile which replace the userprofile with itself there user can select the image

code for edit profile

```
public class Edit_Profile extends Fragment {

com.facebook.Profile userProfile;
EditText editName;
EditText editJob;
EditText editBio;
EditText editEmail;
EditText editPhone;
int SELECT_IMAGE = 1; // global
ImageView profilePicture;
String selectedImagePath;
Bitmap pro_Pic;
File imgFile;
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageRef;

String userName;
String job = null;
String bio = null;
String email = null;
String phone = null;
String institudeID;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    bundle = this.getArguments();
    institudeID = bundle.getString("id");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_edit_profile, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    initialize();

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editback);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    });

    ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editaccept);
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(institudeID).child("User")
                    .child(userProfile.getId().toString());
            User user = new User(editName.getText().toString(), editJob.getText().toString(), editBio.getText().toString()
                    , "Profile/P" + userProfile.getId().toString() + ".jpg", editEmail.getText().toString()
                    , editPhone.getText().toString());
            ref.setValue(user);

            uploadImage();
        }
    });

    ImageView pic = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
}

public void initialize(){
    userProfile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();

    //selectedImagePath = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userProfile.getId() + "/picture?type=large";

    profilePicture = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    editName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editJob = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editJob);
    editBio = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editBio);
    editEmail = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editPhone = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editPhone);


    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://thread-4cc4e.appspot.com");

    if(bundle.getBoolean("register", false)){
        Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userProfile.getId() + "/picture?type=large")
                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                .into(profilePicture);
    }else{
        retrieveProfile();
    }
}

public void retrieveProfile(){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(institudeID).child("User")
            .child(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId().toString());
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            userName = user.getName();
            job = user.getJob();
            bio = user.getBio();
            email = user.getEmail();
            phone = user.getPhoneNo();
            editName.setText(userName);
            editJob.setText(job);
            editBio.setText(bio);
            editEmail.setText(email);
            editPhone.setText(phone);

            downloadImage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);


}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(selectedImageUri)
                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                    .into(profilePicture);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}


public void uploadImage(){
    StorageReference profileImagesRef = storageRef.child("Profile/P" + userProfile.getId().toString() + ".jpg");

    profilePicture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    profilePicture.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = profilePicture.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    UploadTask uploadTask = profileImagesRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    });
}

void downloadImage(){
    StorageReference gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://thread-4cc4e.appspot.com/Profile/P"
            + userProfile.getId().toString() + ".jpg");

    gsReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                    .load(uri)
                    .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                    .resize(400, 400)
                    .into(profilePicture);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: How do you show the edit fragment

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin i FragmentTransaction to replace the fragment here's the code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code

Comment: remove this line in the listener **startActivity(intent);**

Comment: (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.topic);  it's look strange . Are you in fragment or activity ?

Comment: @QuokMoon i am in fragment and the above code is from editprofile for selecting the image

Comment: Where did you define onCreateView method ?

Comment: @QuokMoon i have updated the question with code please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `startActivity(intent);`  from your click listener. `startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);` is use for start acticity  and get back result in `onActivityResult()`.  you not need to call `startActivity()` again.

```
 discPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
               // **startActivity(intent);**
            }
        });
```

I have checked your Code your, you are doing fragment transition in `OnStart()` Method. So on `onStart()` again call when your control return back from gallery.

Please Write your Fragmnet replace Logic in `onCreate()` or maintain Boolean for your `onStart()` Logic.

These Activity Lifecycle Methos are call when your contrl return back into the app

```
  onRestart() --> onStart() --> onResume()

OnCreate() call only once, so do your code here  for fragment replace
```

Comment: @NischalAndroid it didn't work. As i said after the image is selected and the prevoius activity is resumed it starts with the userprofile fragment not with editProfile.

Comment: @NischalAndroid i have added more code please take a look

Comment: I have update my answer Check and Let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
            startActivity(intent);

You are calling startActivityForResult and startActivity at the same time. Use ONly startActivityForResult .

and also Make changes on "onActivityResult" and include  super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data) in code then try if it work for you